How to add minutes to a timestamp in Spark SQL?
I have a SQL Server code snippet where the stored procedure uses the DATEADD function to add minutes to a timestamp.
Here's the code:
DATEADD(minute, no_of_minutes_to_add, timestamp_column) AS new_timestamp

My requirement is to convert this stored procedure code into pyspark SQL code.
I need to run the same code in Spark SQL. However, while Spark SQL does have a DATE_ADD function, it only allows adding a number of days, without a parameter to specify minutes, days, or months.
What is the correct way to add minutes to a timestamp in Spark SQL?
Is there an equivalent function or a workaround to achieve this in Spark SQL?

Does this answer your question? How too add Minutes to datetime in pyspark

I'd do it this way:
import datetime
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

# Add 10 minutes to current timestamp.
datepart = 'minute'
number = 10

schema = StructType([StructField("current_timestamp", TimestampType(), True)])
df = spark.createDataFrame([(datetime.datetime.now(),)], schema)
df.show(truncate=False)

+--------------------------+
|current_timestamp         |
+--------------------------+
|2024-05-07 06:10:19.994861|
+--------------------------+

df = df.withColumn('updated_timestamp', df['current_timestamp'] + expr(f"INTERVAL {number} {datepart}"))
df.show(truncate=False)

+--------------------------+------------------------------+
|current_timestamp         |updated_timestamp             |
+--------------------------+------------------------------+
|2024-05-07 06:10:19.994861|2024-05-07 06:20:19.994861    |
+--------------------------+------------------------------+


EDIT: With parameterized SQL available in Spark 3.4
data = [
    {"product_id": 1, "ts": "2024-05-01 01:00:01.101"},
    {"product_id": 1, "ts": "2024-05-02 01:00:02.212"},
    {"product_id": 1, "ts": "2024-05-03 01:00:03.323"},
    {"product_id": 2, "ts": "2024-05-01 01:00:04.434"},
    {"product_id": 2, "ts": "2024-05-02 01:00:05.545"},
    {"product_id": 2, "ts": "2024-05-03 01:00:06.656"},
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data)

interval_value = 78
datepart = "minute"
timestamp_column = "ts"

query = f"""
select ts AS original_timestamp,
       {{df.{timestamp_column}}} + 
       interval {{interval_value}} {datepart} as modified_timestamp
  from {{df}}"""

spark.sql(
    query,
    interval_value=interval_value,
    df=df,
).show(truncate=False)

+-----------------------+-----------------------+
|original_timestamp     |modified_timestamp     |
+-----------------------+-----------------------+
|2024-05-01 01:00:01.101|2024-05-01 02:18:01.101|
|2024-05-02 01:00:02.212|2024-05-02 02:18:02.212|
|2024-05-03 01:00:03.323|2024-05-03 02:18:03.323|
|2024-05-01 01:00:04.434|2024-05-01 02:18:04.434|
|2024-05-02 01:00:05.545|2024-05-02 02:18:05.545|
|2024-05-03 01:00:06.656|2024-05-03 02:18:06.656|
+-----------------------+-----------------------+



how do we add {number} if we have the entire SQL in string """SELECT * ..."

Added an example. See if this helps.

interval_value  is dynamic and it is a column in a table

The snippet I posted should get you going, but if this doesn't help, please post a complete SQL example where you have the problem.

It got resolved we used udf approach
